# How can I ensure that my home LAN is not affected by my cable modem's outage

Tags: networking, dhcp, isp

As probably with most of the world, my cable modem experiences downtime intermittently each day (for maybe several minutes).

The problem is, I use my cable modem for DHCP - I have a switch connected to one of it's LAN outputs and have a number of computers connected to the switch. Everything is wired, no wireless.

When the cable modem experiences an ISP issue (for whatever reason), then my entire home LAN becomes inaccessible - I cannot ping one of my linux machines to another, my Samba shares are not accessible, and so forth.

I understand of course that I cannot make connections to the internet, but I was hoping at least my home LAN would be unaffected (i.e. home machine A communicating with home machine B).

Would anyone have suggestions on how I can insulate my home LAN operation from intermittent outages in my cable modem for the internet?

Thanks, I appreciate.

Comment: Most probably you are experiencing not ISP issue, but hardware issue. Cheaper modems/routers has less RAM memory. Each time devices in your LAN connect to outside world, an entry created in the memory for modem/router could forward response back to proper device. Sometimes many devices create many connectios and then memory got exhausted. Typically modem/router would reboot to clear the memory. At this time LAN connections are unavailable as well. Check your modem logs and memory usage at the statistics page.

Comment: Things don't quite make sense here. Failure of the WAN link shouldn't affect your LAN at all. DHCP is implemented in software on your modem and completely independent from the ISP or WAN status. Failure of DHCP wouldn't prevent devices that already have their IPs assigned from communicating over the LAN. How are you checking connectivity between computers? (let's stick to the ones connected through a switch for now)

Comment: @Ceremony - you should properly create an account here, **linking your Server Fault account**. Then you will be able to comment under your own question.

Comment: @gronostaj - pls take a look at his comment (I'm not sure if he'll be able to post here...) https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1052937

Comment: How are you checking connectivity between computers?

Comment: **Would anyone have suggestions on how I can insulate my home LAN operation from intermittent outages in my cable modem for the internet?** - Run your own DHCP server and stop using the DHCP server from the modem.

Answer (score 0):

You're "Unable to ping from one machine to another" has got nothing to do with a WAN outage.

It sounds like you're using your cable modem as a network switch as well as a gateway. It sounds like your cable modem is having a problem that would be best fixed by getting a real switch for you computers to plug into and then from that switch to your cable modem. If you already have a real switch I'd look at replacing it.

Unrelated I'd also recommend that you get a raspberry-pi (or similar) and install pihole on it to act as DHCP, DNS resolver and adblocker.

Answer (score 0):

I would either do as has already been suggested, and set up a pi for DNS/DHCP, or do as I have done myself, set up a router between your cable moden and your other gear. you could install openwrt on the router, and use that to run custom sofware, the advantage being dedicated hardware, and potential reviews to help you find a good router.